# react-router-dom not working as expected with routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm understanding the react-router-dom library and the components that provide the routing and noticed a strange behavior as below.

Assume we have our App.js component which return JSX code as below.

```
import './App.css';
import ColorAdder from './ColorAdder';
import {Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
  
  return (
  <Switch>
     <ColorAdder/>
     <Route path="/hello" exact>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </Route>
   </Switch>    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now the component `ColorAdder.js` also consists of Routes with `Path` and `exact` attributes declared as below.

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
const ColorAdder = ()=>{
  return (
    <Route path="/hi" exact>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </Route>
  )
}
export default ColorAdder;
```

The App.js is wrapped with `<BrowserRouter>` and what i noticed is when we test the page with url `http://localhost:3002/hi` it returned Hi as expected but it does n't return anything for 'http://localhost:3002/hello'.why does it behave this way ? Can anyone please explain this behavior why the `Route` with path `hello` is not identified even when it is under `Switch` wrapping and with `Path` and `exact` attributes

Below is the `Index.js` using `BrowserRouter`

```
ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App/></BrowserRouter>,document.getElementById('render'))
```

[image: When the path is "/hi"]
[image: when the path is "/hello"]

Versions:
react-router-dom@5,
npm - 7.20.3,
node - v16.7.0

Comment: In newer version switch is replaced with Routes
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview
take a look

Answer (score 1):

first, its good practice to have routing logic in app.js plus don't render `<ColorAdder/>` inside the switch instead use the *component* attribute in  like this:-

**your App.js : -**

```
import './App.css';
import ColorAdder from './ColorAdder';
import {Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  
  return (
  <Switch>
     <Route path="/hi" component={colorAdder} exact></Route>
// if you have other routes do like this 
 <Route path="/hello" component={<p>hello</p>} exact></Route>
  // instead of hard coding <p>hello </p> here you can create a separate component that render the helloComponent
   </Switch>    
  );
}
```

**your ColorAdder.js :-**  it should only return the content cuz the routing logic is done in app.js

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
const ColorAdder = ()=>{
  return (
    <p> h1 </p>
  )
}
export default ColorAdder;
```

**NB :- BrowserRouter should be inside index.js it should wrap the app component**

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
```

Comment: Thank you, App component is wrapped with <BrowserRouter/> in the index.js. The Routing can be included anywhere and so is the reason to specify the BrowserRouter at the App.js level. 
So, here the ColorAdder component should work when the Routes are placed inside it.
If i follow the approach of placing the routes as suggested then it would n't be clumspy to have hundreds of routes in one single component ? i would rather prefer to break the routes in multiple components to take the BrowserRouter advantage and it could also be a bug from react-router-dom ?

Comment: you can have multiple components doing the routings  but in programming there is a nice principle  Single Responsibility principle which states that a class should have only one responsibility, getting back to our problem its better to do the routing logic in one component , file whether app.js or router.js or another file the most important thing is that whenever you want to add, modify route stuff it will be easy for u to go to that file and modify instead searching which file to modify hope it helps

Comment: Ok..but technically the Route defined outside "ColorAdder" is supposed to work and for the app scalability we have classified the routes (lets say those deal with the user) are under one component and those deal with Product are under another component. Its easy to identify which path to modify in the future and where to look at if the paths and routes are classified rather than having one huge component with thousands of routes and paths defined in one file and all these are opinionated though. I'm suspecting if its a bug from react-router-dom library itself.

Comment: if it's preferable for you, you can do that i was just recommending the best practices though , btw what is the bug from react-router-dom ?

Comment: The Route described outside ColorAdder.js and the one in App.js should be identified. Please check the screenshots. Having lean code and classified information is also a best practice. React is designed to do the heavy lifting and rendering wherever we want so the routes can't be confined at only place and should be flexible.

Comment: no its not abug brother if you install 'react-router-dom' you can access its features in all over your project directories , have nice day Anon ! enjoy it

Comment: it's supposed to access in this case as well Ahmed..thanks..i will discuss it in the react-router forums..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240265/discussion-between-anoncrack-and-ahmed-hosny).